# nested XSL: sort

Tags: xml, xslt

I am a beginner struggling with sorting.
My XML file is as follows:

```
<livre>
    <p>Aa. 1a. l) Livre d’Isaïe <?pages?>30, 106, 124.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>34</number>, <number>1</number> <?pages?>36.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>40</number>-50 <?pages?>299.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>42</number>, <number>6</number> <?pages?>696.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>44</number>, <number>13</number>-15 <?pages?>730.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>45</number>, <number>1</number> <?pages?>299.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>49</number>, <number>6</number> <?pages?>30, 658, 696.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>56</number>-66 <?pages?>244.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>60</number>, <number>3</number> <?pages?>699.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>66</number>, <number>1</number>-2 <?pages?>284.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>66</number>, <number>20</number> <?pages?>699.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>7</number>, <number>14</number> <?pages?>246.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. l0) Is <number>2</number>, <number>2</number>-5 <?pages?>699.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. l0) Is <number>2</number>, <number>3</number> <?pages?>696.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. l0) Is <number>11</number>, <number>12</number> <?pages?>30.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. m) Livre de Jérémie <?pages?>105, 106, 113, 115, 124, 301, 661.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>7</number>, <number>1</number>-20 <?pages?>353.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>10</number>, <number>11</number> <?pages?>104.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>13</number>, <number>14</number> <?pages?>30.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>13</number>, <number>27</number> <?pages?>353.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>25</number>, <number>11</number>-12 <?pages?>57.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>25</number>, <number>34</number> <?pages?>30.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>29</number>, <number>1</number>-23 <?pages?>661.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>29</number>, <number>4</number>-7 <?pages?>661.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>29</number>, <number>10</number> <?pages?>57.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. mb) Jr <number>29</number>, <number>24</number>-32 <?pages?>661.<?pages?></p>
</livre>
```

I need to sort the text nodes of the p element preceding the first number element in alphabetical order (as they are now) and then the first number elements in numerical order, and then the second ones, if necessary, and so on.

```
<livre>
    <p>Aa. 1a. l) Livre d’Isaïe <?pages?>30, 106, 124.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. l) Is <number>2</number>, <number>2</number>-5 <?pages?>699.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. l) Is <number>2</number>, <number>3</number> <?pages?>696.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. l) Is <number>11</number>, <number>12</number> <?pages?>30.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>7</number>, <number>14</number> <?pages?>246.<?pages?></p>        
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>34</number>, <number>1</number> <?pages?>36.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>40</number>-50 <?pages?>299.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>42</number>, <number>6</number> <?pages?>696.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>44</number>, <number>13</number>-15 <?pages?>730.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>45</number>, <number>1</number> <?pages?>299.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>49</number>, <number>6</number> <?pages?>30, 658, 696.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>56</number>-66 <?pages?>244.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>60</number>, <number>3</number> <?pages?>699.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>66</number>, <number>1</number>-2 <?pages?>284.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is <number>66</number>, <number>20</number> <?pages?>699.<?pages?></p>
    
    
    <p>Aa. 1a. m) Livre de Jérémie <?pages?>105, 106, 113, 115, 124, 301, 661.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>7</number>, <number>1</number>-20 <?pages?>353.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>10</number>, <number>11</number> <?pages?>104.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>13</number>, <number>14</number> <?pages?>30.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>13</number>, <number>27</number> <?pages?>353.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>25</number>, <number>11</number>-12 <?pages?>57.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>25</number>, <number>34</number> <?pages?>30.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>29</number>, <number>1</number>-23 <?pages?>661.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>29</number>, <number>4</number>-7 <?pages?>661.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr <number>29</number>, <number>10</number> <?pages?>57.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. mb) Jr <number>29</number>, <number>24</number>-32 <?pages?>661.<?pages?></p>
</livre>
```

I believe I should do a for-each-group which captures the first text child of p and a nested sort inside of it but I cannot seem to find the right way of doing it.
Would you mind helping me?
Thank you very much.

Here's one of the XSLT codes I tried:

```
    <p><xsl:for-each select=".//p">
            <xsl:sort select="substring-before(., ')')"  data-type="text"></xsl:sort>
        
<xsl:apply-templates select="." >
            <xsl:sort select="number[1]" data-type="number" order="ascending"></xsl:sort>
</xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each>
</p></xsl:template>
```

Comment: The input sample has some data like `<p>Aa. 1a. l0) Is ` that is not even appearing in the output. So do you need to perform more than sorting? Anyway, in XSLT 3 with `sort` function and higher-order support (for Saxon HE only in version 10.x) you might be able to use `<xsl:sequence select="sort(p, (), function($p) { $p/text()[1], $p/number/xs:integer(.) })"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this can work for you:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/livre">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-starting-with="p[not(number)]">
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:sort select="number[1]" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:sort select="number[2]" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what I needed!